# Is this sentence correct 很多人需开始工作得帮家

Tags: translation, word-choice, meaning-in-context, usage, phrase

I'm making a text for a test and I ended up with this sentence 很多人需开始工作得帮家. What I'm Trying to say is:

*Many people need to start working to help their families*

It's a complex phrase for my level and I'm not sure if it's correct mostly because of the caracterization of 工作. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not correct.

1. We use 以 to start a reason clause that is at the end of the sentence. Hence 以帮家, not 得帮家. (If you place reason clause at the front, use 为 or 为了.)
2. For rhythmic reasons, modern Chinese tends to use two-character words. Hence 帮助家庭, not 帮家. 帮 can be used when there are more words after the object, like 我帮家人干活.

If you just need a faithful translation then 很多人需开始工作以帮助家庭 would probably work. To make it more natural, you can replace 需 with 不得不 (implying the people were forced to go to work), and replace 帮助家庭 with 帮家庭减轻负担 (reduce the burden).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the concept is quite clear. Maybe some rich, spoilt kids, plagued by their slowly developing consciences, decide to get a job to contribute to the family fortune, but most people get a job to have a life and pay their way.

Many people need to start working to help their families financially.
许多人不得不开始工作以在经济上帮助他们的家庭.

Answer (score 0):

Many people need to start working to help their families.

很多人需要**去**工作，**来**支持家庭生活。

**去**工作 = to start working

**来**支持 = to help